# loading an external c++ function from an HTML page

Tags: c#, c++, html, qt, webkit

I am trying to develop an HTML page (internal of course) that can in some way be able to load another application. I don't mind using any language to do that. I am using a webkit interface to render the HTML page (well, it QTWebKit) and sadly it does not allow using ActiveXObject (JavaScript) to be used to call another app. I am not sure if this is possible but hopefully it is.

As I said, I don't mind using any kind of script or methods to do that (as long as its user friendly).

So my question in short: Can I load an external c++/c# function from a dll and call the functions directly from an HTML page.

Comment: Are you embedding QTWebKit in a custom applicaton that you're writing?  Or are you just writing an HTML page to be loaded in a normal Web browser?

Comment: I am embedding QTWebKit in a custom application...

Answer (score 3):

With QtWebKit you can easily expose objects to script using [`QWebFrame::addToJavaScriptWindowObject()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwebframe.html#addToJavaScriptWindowObject), see e.g. [this blog post](https://blogs.kde.org/2009/07/05/adding-custom-objects-qt-webkit) for an example.

If you want a plugin that works in all browsers except IE, use [NPAPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NPAPI) or one of its wrappers. If you want to support all browsers including IE, you can simplify your work by using a framework like [FireBreath](http://code.google.com/p/firebreath/).

Comment: broken link on "this blog post"

Comment: Great, now that you've fixed that and I have this working, can you help me make it work on an IFRAME? http://stackoverflow.com/q/33599474/105539